# RC Snubber for synchronous MOSFET (SMPS)

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, resonance, snubber

I am trying to understand the theory of RC snubber for synchronous buck converters. Some statements seem to be contradictory to me in the below mentioned application notes:

1. “The snubber capacitance is designed to block lower frequencies (such as the switching frequency) but appears as a short at the ringing frequency. “
   http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slpa010/slpa010.pdf - Page 12
2. “It is important to notice that only the magnitude of the ringing was affected by the boot-resistor and gate resistor methods. The snubber method also changed the ringing frequency and damped out the ringing waveform”
   http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt465/slyt465.pdf - Page 6

My doubts:

1. How does the snubber capacitor acts as a short circuit during the ringing frequency ?  After all it is the one which decides the new ringing frequency.
2. Why is Cp (parasitic capacitance) used in the characteristic impedance calculation? The equivalent capacitance should have been considered, which is Cp + Csnubber.

Answer (score 1):

> How does the snubber capacitor acts as a short circuit during the
>   ringing frequency ? After all it is the one which decides the new
>   ringing frequency.

Texas Instruments are somewhat polarizing what happens - it doesn't act as a complete short but it does reduce the ringing frequency AND it also reduces the ringing amplitude. The amplitude reduces because the Q factor of the resonating components is reduced by the snubber resistor.

> Why is Cp (parasitic capacitance) used in the characteristic impedance
>   calculation? The equivalent capacitance should have been considered,
>   which is Cp + Csnubber.

I'm unsure which document you found this statement - maybe you can point it out?

Comment: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slpa010/slpa010.pdf

Comment: Doesn't  the snubber capacitor dictate the new ringing frequency?

If so the resultant circuit looks like a series RLC Circuit, ( RLC being snubber resistance, parasitic inductance, snubber capacitance). But that is not the case as per the application notes

Comment: Page/paragraph number?

Comment: Yes it does - it reduces it as I said in my answer.

Comment: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slpa010/slpa010.pdf

Page 12/ Last para

Comment: You might need to [take the tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to find out why people give up their free time to help - I'm saying this because I notice that you haven't formally accepted any answer to your previous 9 questions. I know you have done so on earlier questions but, let's not be mean here.

Comment: I can't find the term "characteristic impedance" in that document. Please be clear about what you ask.

Comment: Iam so sorry Andy. I completely appreciate the help you and other guys offering. Its just that I took this lightly and didnt realise the bare minimum etiquettes here. Once again thanks for telling me this.

Comment: The term 'characteristic impedance' is not there in this document. But I remember reading it in some other which Iam unable to find now. Square root of L/C is called as the characteristic impedance of an LC circuit

Comment: Sqrt(L/C) is near the optimum Rdampen value for fastest settling. Given the slewing of voltages and the uncertainty of precise timing as inductances change, sqrt(L/C) is a good starting point for thinking.

Comment: Reading between the lines I would say that because the snubber capacitor is used "apply" the snubber resistor to reduce the Q-factor of resonance, the natural impedance (\$\sqrt{L/C}\$) is largely unaffected by whatever value Csnubber is. That's me polarizing things because there are subtleties to this around any resonant point.